# Eliminate Render Blocking Styleetsheet | Performance Improvement javascript | Single page application| angular 1.5x| Google Page Speed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, google-pagespeed, render-blocking

Currently, I am looking for **Performance Improvement in Angular 1.x** version app. When I run the Google Page speed I received **RENDER BLOCKING STYLESHEET** to Optimize the application to get 100/100 Page score.I have found some of the interesting sites and the node module to generate critical render CSS to resolve it.

Received solutions(Works for static pages):

> 1. Critical Node Module
> 2. https://jonassebastianohlsson.com/criticalpathcssgenerator/
> 3. Penthouse Node module

Facing Issue || Doubts (solution required):

> 1. For Single page application, How we can generate the Inline Critical CSS.
> 2. If we have 400 web pages (Not SPA's), how to generate the critical CSS for each page of the Dynamic website which contains different contents and template injection. How can we generate it?Is it possible?
> 3. Is there any plugin or way defined like whenever the page loads It will inject the respective Critical CSS of the page to Internal style tags automatically.?
> 4. Is it possible to generate the critical CSS of the site of 400 Dynamic pages during the build time only? So that it will be easy injected to the particular page
> 5. How can we generate Critical CSS for server-side rendering pages?

***Thanks In Advance***.!! ***Maybe question is big :( but Help required*** .!!